# VSTACK in Excel used to combine two sets of data resulting in calc error if one set is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following function to combine two sets of data.

`=FILTER(VSTACK(FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>""),FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"")),{1,1,1,0,1})`

If there is valid data, it works fine, however if there is no data in one of the datasets it results in a calc error. I have tried protecting against the errors using the following:

`=FILTER(VSTACK(IFERROR(FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>""),""),IFERROR(FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>""),"")),{1,1,1,0,1})`

However this gives a row with N/A in each cell and then follows on with the data defined from S3:W onwards.

Is there a way to protect the FILTERS so it can continue to work should either of the datasets are empty?

Comment: Do you have `CHOOSECOLS`?

Comment: Lightly tested: `=LET(x,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),y, FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),z,VSTACK(x,y),IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(z,(INDEX(z,0,1)<>"")),1,2,3,5),"No data"))`

Comment: Hi Rory, This worked well when there was no data in the first table but when there was none in the second and data in the first it shows no data. Any idea?

Comment: I was just coming back to add that it's probably simpler to stack both ranges first: `=LET(x,CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(M3:Q50000,S3:W50000),1,2,3,5),FILTER(x,INDEX(x,0,1)<>""))`

Comment: Both the datasets are dynamically generated with formulas, when the data in the second was empty it was throwing an error so I caught that and output nothing and it allowed your first suggested formula to work, thanks for this. I'll try the updated mods now

Comment: Hey Rory, I got a calc error with the latest version. The first version works perfectly, whether there's no data in dataset 1, dataset 2 or no data in either. 

`=LET(x,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),y, FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),z,VSTACK(x,y),IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(z,(INDEX(z,0,1)<>"")),1,2,3,5),""))`

Will you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the missing data with something like this:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),y, FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),z,VSTACK(x,y),IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(z,(INDEX(z,0,1)<>"")),1,2,3,5),"No data"))
```

using `CHOOSECOLS` rather than another `FILTER` function.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but what about:

```
=LET(a,FILTER(VSTACK(M3:Q50000,S3:W50000),{1,1,1,0,1}),FILTER(a,TAKE(a,,1)<>"",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on-

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A1:C12,A1:A12<>"",""),y,FILTER(E1:G12,E1:E12<>"",""),IF(AND(x=""),IF(y="","",y),IF(AND(y<>""),VSTACK(x,y),x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun24hr, the solution seems to work great in resolving the error with a blank dataset. However, is it possible to retain the filter to drop out the 4th column when constructing the new combined data as per my original formula?

I tried the following but it just didn't do anything : 

`=LET(table1,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),table2,FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),IF(AND(table1=""),IF(table2="","", table2),IF(AND(table2<>""), FILTER(VSTACK(table1, table2),{1,1,1,0,1}),table1)))`

Comment: I also tried the following but no luck: 

`=LET(table1,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),table2,FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),tableMerge, VSTACK(table1, table2),sortedTable, FILTER(tableMerge,{1,1,1,0,1}),IF(AND(table1=""),IF(table2="","", table2),IF(AND(table2<>""), sortedTable, table1)))`

Comment: I got it working with the following 

`=LET(table1,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),
table2,FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),
tableMerge, VSTACK(table1, table2),
sortedTable, FILTER(tableMerge,{1,1,1,0,1}),
IF(AND(table1=""),IF(table2="","", table2),IF(AND(table2<>""), INDEX(tableMerge,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tableMerge)),{1,2,3,5}), table1)))`

However, if there is no data in table1 it shows the whole of table2 and viceversa, showing the 4th column that I want to exclude

Comment: After trying the following it removes the 4th column but gives N/A in to the 5th when there's no data in table1
`
=LET(
table1,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),
table2,FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),
tableMerge, VSTACK(table1, table2),
sortedTableMerge, INDEX(tableMerge,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tableMerge)),{1,2,3,5}),
sortedTable1, INDEX(table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(table1)),{1,2,3,5}),
sortedTable2, INDEX(table2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(table2)),{1,2,3,5}),
IF(AND(table1=""),IF(table2="","", sortedTable2),IF(AND(table2<>""), sortedTableMerge, sortedTable1)))`

Comment: Using the suggestion from Rory for CHOOSECOLS I get the same result as my previous comment, so N/A showing in column 5

`=LET(
table1,FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>"",""),
table2,FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"",""),
tableMerge, VSTACK(table1, table2),
sortedTableMerge, CHOOSECOLS(tableMerge,1,2,3,5),
sortedTable1, CHOOSECOLS(table1,1,2,3,5),
sortedTable2, CHOOSECOLS(table2,1,2,3,5),
IF(AND(table1=""),IF(table2="","", sortedTable2),IF(AND(table2<>""), sortedTableMerge, sortedTable1)))`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easier solution to this, now with `CHOOSECOLS`.
Try the following code:

```
=iferror(choosecols(VSTACK(FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>""),FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"")),{1,2,3,4}),choosecols(FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"")),{1,2,3,4}))
```